# How to setState by ref dynamically in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this

```
 handleChange(e){

    this.setState(
        update(this.state, {
            user: {
                $merge: {
                    firstname_user: this.firstname_user.refs.input.value,
                    lastname_user: this.lastname_user.refs.input.value,
                    password_user: this.password_user.refs.input.value,
                    newPassword_user: this.newPassword_user.refs.input.value,
                    confirmPassword_user: this.confirmPassword_user.refs.input.value,
                }
            }
        })
    )

 }
```

I would like to do only one generic `setState`.

Because currently, when I change one input, all my values are changed by `setState`.

I tried something like this, but I can accessed to the `ref`. The key `[e.target.name]` works, but with the same approach the value doesn't work.

```
    this.setState(
        update(this.state, {
            user: {
                $merge: {
                    [e.target.name]: this.[e.target.name].refs.input.value,
                }
            }
        })
    );
```

How to solve that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a syntax error, try this instead :

```
$merge: {
    [e.target.name]: this[e.target.name].refs.input.value,
}
```